# admob on iOS - test ads don't work, but real ads do

Tags: ios, size, admob

```
 _adMob = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeLeaderboard origin:CGPointZero];
 _adMob.frame = CGRectMake(148, 0, 728, 90);
```

I'm using that above code in my project, but when i turn on test ads in the createRequest methods, I get the error `Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show.` If i turn test mode off, I get ads. Test mode and normal mode worked when i used `kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape` but I heard that smart banners aren't good for revenue.

Would you say I should just submit my iPad app without fixing this issue? Otherwise how would I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You Cant Use This mode for ipad Not for iPhone. If you run on iPhone device then crush ...Read below

// Landscape size for the iPad. Typically 728x90.

```
 extern GADAdSize const kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;
```

Comment: Sorry if i didn't put enough detail, the smart banner did work but i don't want to use it because i've found that it creates lower revenue. I grid to use the leaderboard size but thats where i get the error. I'm using iPad only not iPhone

Comment: Hello? are you still there?